# Visual Basic 6: Winsock, Use a port already in use

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, winsock

I'm trying to send data on the same port another application is.

```
winsock1.localport=4001
```

But when I bind it, winsock will not allow me.

How do I use a port already in use? (Local)

Comment: #1, if you are writing a TCP client, don't do it.  Find another port; better-still, let windows find one for you

Comment: no it's udp! :D with tcp isn't almost impossible because you require a real connection, udp packets are like raw sockets. So if I were to do it with UDP how would I 'share' ports?

Answer (score 0):

If this were possible, would it not break the concept of sockets?

Rgds,
Martin